# KendoUI Symfony3 Twig

Tags: php, symfony, kendo-ui, twig, kendo-grid

So, I followed tutorial for setting all js and css files for kendo for jquery. Now, here is the problem:

I have one main twig called main.html.twig where i call all the main scripts

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/kendo.all.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Im using webpack so build/kendo_js is just where the files are stored.

Now, when I want to build a kendo grid in new html that is extending the previous one (base.html.twig) I cannot access to kendoGrid function. But, if I write it like this in the base.html.twig:

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/kendo.all.min.js') }}"></script>

<script> 
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({

    });
</script>
```

It works.

Im guessing there is a problem with the scope, but im not sure how to fix it.

Anyone any clues on this?